# clock() doesn't work correctly

Tags: c, datetime, clock

My code looks like this:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    time_t loop_begin, loop_end, scanf_begin, scanf_end;
    double loop_time, scanf_time;
    int q;


    loop_begin = clock();
    //some big loop
    loop_end = clock();

    loop_time = (double)(loop_end - loop_begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("%.6f\n", loop_time);


    scanf_begin = clock();
    printf("qwe> ");scanf("%d", &q);
    scanf_end = clock();

    scanf_time = (double)(scanf_end - scanf_begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("%.6f\n", scanf_time);

    return 0;
}
```

But the output is like this:

```
20.087593
qwe> 543       
0.000073
```

Am I missing something or is this normal? If this is normal, what would you suggest?

Comment: What are you expecting different?

Comment: @Blindy, second time to be something like 5.

Comment: Are you asking if it is normal for your "some big loop" to take longer than for a user to write "543"?!?

Comment: _clock() doesn't work correctly_ - well, that's one explanation. Do you think it's the right one though?

Comment: @dovetalk, 0.000073 seconds doesn't seem real.

Comment: @user3121023, tried, same result.

Comment: @mah, ya sorry, I couldn't find a better title.

Comment: From what I can see, the `clock()` function measures _processor time_, not real time. There isn't much processing being done to print some output and scan some input - it's simple data motion. If the user gets a cup of coffee in the middle, the processing time here is 0 because the processor is waiting for an interrupt (or off doing things that don't get counted in this process's time).

Comment: @mah, thank you for explaining, what would you suggest for real time? Or is there such a thing in C?

Comment: You have `time()` for wall clock time in C.

Comment: Use `gettimeofday`. It returns a `timeval` struct which gives you the time in seconds and microsconds. `clock()` returns a number of ticks, which can roll over at any time.

Comment: @dovetalk, gettimeofday looks pretty good. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`clock` measures CPU time. When your program is waiting for your keypresses, it is blocked in a system call and does not use any processor time.

From Linux Programmer's Manual:

> **NAME**
>
> `clock` - determine processor time
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> #include <time.h>
> clock_t clock(void);
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The clock() function returns an approximation of **processor time used by the program.**
>
> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> The  value  returned is the CPU time used so far as a `clock_t`; to get the number 
>   of seconds **used**, divide by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`.  If the processor time used is not 
>   available or its value cannot be represented, the function returns the value `(clock_t) -1.`